# $.css('transform') return wrong value rotate

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get element -moz-transform:rotate value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery)

**Firefox 15 - Chrome:**

```
$('#img2').css('transform');

return =>  "rotate(90deg)"
```

**Firefox 16**

```
$('#img2').css('transform');
return => matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Any idea how to get rotate value in firefox 16
What is matrix ?

In Firebq i get:

```
element.style {
    height: auto;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Firefox 15 returns the same thing as Firefox 16 here...  And both seem to return the used transform value, whereas Chrome is returning the computed one.  The spec on which one is right is still up in the air.

Answer (score 6):

A matrix is an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) in the form `[a,b,c,d,tx,ty]`. If you parse the css string into an object with those properties (respectively `[0,1,-1,0,0,0]` in your example), then you can calculate the angle of rotation in degrees by doing: `Math.atan2(matrix.b,matrix.a) * (180 / Math.PI);`

There's a good article on the css matrix here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/ - but still the best explanation I've found is this one by Senocular (even though it's meant to be about Flash, the basic math is the same): http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

The `rotate(deg)` syntax is just a shorthand for the underlying matrix transform. I'm not sure why FF accepts one format, but reports another.

More on transforms: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/

Comment: source: http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Comment: @Userpassword That wasn't my source, but it's another useful link.

Comment: ok i try make jqueyr function that work with chrome and firefox15/16

Comment: OK is duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery

Comment: Oh yes. Probably best to delete then.

Comment: But google search right now are shity, i try find solution for about 10 minutes and nothing show maybe this will be helpfully to somebody.

Comment: Ok - your question, so of course your prerogative.