# How to get the value of -webkit-transform with jquery

Tags: jquery, 3d

My CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg);
```

Method to get transform value:

```
var matrix = $item.css("transform");
```

Then I get the value like this:

```
matrix3d(0.707107, 0, 0.707107, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.707107, 0, 0.707107, 0, 350, 0, -200, 1)
```

Question:

```
How can I get the rorateY value?
```

Comment: http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897291/csstransform-return-wrong-value-rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897291/csstransform-return-wrong-value-rotate)

Comment: no,that is 2D,mine is 3D