# CSS Rotate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, rotatetransform

I'm trying to do a clock with css rotate and jquery. The rotate part is done, but now i have to do a spin in the clock and stop at the time of computer's user.

The part i can't do is the spin and stop at the right time. My code, now, is:

```
function horario(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();

    var hourDegraus = hour * 30;
    var minuteDegraus = minutes * 6;

    $(".pont-hour").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + hourDegraus + 'deg)'});
    $(".pont-hour").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + hourDegraus + 'deg)'});
    $(".pont-hour").css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + hourDegraus + 'deg)'});
    $(".pont-minutes").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + minuteDegraus + 'deg)'});
    $(".pont-minutes").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + minuteDegraus + 'deg)'});
    $(".pont-minutes").css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + minuteDegraus + 'deg)'});
}
```

Basically, i want to do a spin and in the end the pointers stop at the time in variables hourDegraus and minuteDegraus.

Any idea how i can do the spin?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191058/css-rotation-cross-browser-with-jquery-animate

Comment: Also, frenchie's link points out that vendor prefixes are automatically applied in jQuery 1.8+.

Comment: @frenchie Wow, i take a look at this question and i can do the effect with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15191130/3642593 . Unfortunately, the effect is too "fast" and i can't add some animate (duration) or something. There's a way?

Comment: just change the duration property and add some more time if needed; for now it's set at 2000.

Comment: @frenchie Hmm, i'm using this code: http://jsbin.com/ofagog/2/edit and don't have a duration time :(. Maybe i got the wrong code?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the duration; just insert the line "duration: 5000," right above the line "step: function(now, fx){" Like this: http://jsbin.com/puxezosa/1/edit