# Who can fill this shape with color using JQuery animation?

Tags: jquery-animate, css-animations

**I am thinking if you can fill this shape with color using JQuery animation starting from point A to point B to make color flow gradually.**

This is the shape:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x19dcjcqdoh3j9i/spiral%20shape.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with jQuery, but you would need your shape outline to have a solid white background, and transparent where the fill will go.

You could then place an image behind it which rotates and reduces in size as the animation progresses.

Comment: I can make 2 images one above another but how to animate. Could you  give any URL which includes tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191058/css-rotation-cross-browser-with-jquery-animate