# Rotate element to click position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have a project with a circle that, when clicked, rotates to a predefined position.  It is almost there, but the last requirement is that it always rotates clockwise to the marker.  I just can't seem to figure out how to get the right value so that when i set css transform:rotate(Xdeg), it will always go clockwise.  Keeping the angle between 0 and 360 would also be a plus for another piece of this, but not necessary.

See this fiddle, javascript below as well    [Rotation](http://jsfiddle.net/2g17cjuL/1/)

```
$(function () {
$('body').on('click', '#graph1', function (e) {

    console.log('********************');
    //get mouse position relative to div and center of div for polar origin
    var pos = getMousePosAndCenter(e, 'graph1');

    //get the current degrees of rotation from the css
    var currentRotationDegrees = getCSSRotation('#graph1');
    console.log('CSS Rotation Value: ' + currentRotationDegrees);

    //current rotation in radians
    var currentRotationRadians = radians(currentRotationDegrees);

    //radians where clicked
    var clickRadiansFromZero = Math.atan2(pos.y - pos.originY, pos.x - pos.originX);

    //degrees the click is offset from 0 origin
    var offsetDegrees = degrees(clickRadiansFromZero);

    //how many degrees to rotate in css to put the mouse click at 0
    var degreesToZero;
    if (offsetDegrees >= 0)
        degreesToZero = currentRotationDegrees - Math.abs(offsetDegrees);
    else
        degreesToZero = currentRotationDegrees + Math.abs(offsetDegrees);

    console.log("Degrees to Zero: " + degreesToZero);

    //distance in pixels from origin
    var distance = calculateDistance(pos.originX, pos.originY, pos.x, pos.y);

    console.log("Distance From Origin(px): " + distance);

    $('#graph1').css('transform','rotate(' + degreesToZero + 'deg)')
});

});

function getMousePosAndCenter(e, id) {
    var rect = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (((e.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * rect.width) + 0.5 << 0,
        y: (((e.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * rect.height) + 0.5 << 0,
        originY: (rect.height / 2),
        originX: (rect.width / 2)
    };
}

function radians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};

function degrees(radians) {
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
};

function calculateDistance(originX, originY, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - originX, 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - originY, 2)));
}

function getCSSRotation(id) {
    var matrix = $(id).css('transform');
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1],
    values = values.split(')')[0],
    values = values.split(',');

    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var c = values[2];
    var d = values[3];

    var cssRotation = degrees(Math.atan2(b, a));
    return cssRotation;
}
```

Comment: Added a fiddle to my answer, that gives you the fluid framerate of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Think out of the box:**
We can `CSS3 rotate` an element with `transform` to i.e: **720°** ...
it will make 2 **clockwise** turns. *(OK, in our **UI** it can only do max a 359 turn but let's follow the math)*
If we than animate it to **810°**... it just means that **it'll do a 90° clockwise move**!

So all we need to do is **always increase a degree variable *to insanity!***

HEY! If at some point you want to keep track of the current **normalized** 0-360 degree...
 **you can always retrieve that value** doing `ourCurrentInsanelyHighDegree % 360 = UIdegrees`

***[Here's a jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/miluru/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

and this is all the JS you need.

```js
function getCSSRotation( $el ) {
  var matrix = $el.css('transform'),
      v = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
      rds = Math.atan2(v[1], v[0]);
  return rds*180/Math.PI <<0; // Degrees
}

var $EL = $("#graph1"),
  w = $EL.width(),
  r = w/2,                             // Radius
  x = parseInt($EL.css("left"), 10),
  y = parseInt($EL.css("top"),  10),
  d = getCSSRotation( $EL );           // Initial degree (ONLY ONCE!)

$EL.on("click", function(e){
  var mx = e.clientX-x-r,              // Click coord X
      my = e.clientY-y-r,              // Click coord Y
      rds = Math.atan2(-my, -mx),      // Radians
      md = (rds*180/Math.PI<<0) + 180; // Mouse Degrees
  d += (360-md);                       // always increment to insanity!!
  $(this).css({transform:"rotate("+ d +"deg)"});
});
```

```css
#graph1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;    left:30px;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    background:url(//placehold.it/200x200&text=IMAGE);
    transition:transform 2s ease;
    transform:rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
#marker {
    position: absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:230px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph1"></div>
<div id="marker">Wherever you click, it rotates to here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: 
Figuring it would be easy to do, I found it a little harder than I thought. The other answer with jQuery.animate works, but animate doesn't have the fluid framerate that css animation does (it runs on the GPU).

Here's a modified fiddle with a CSS solution: **http://jsfiddle.net/2g17cjuL/2/**

> Keeping the angle between 0 and 360 would also be a plus

You cannot keep going forward (ie rotating by a positive number) and keep the rotation positive, however, in my fiddle `offsetDegrees` (the number of degrees additional rotated), or the remainder of `totalDegrees`divided by 360 should give you what you need to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Requrement:** That it always rotates clockwise.

One thing: If you use CSS transitions, it'll calculate the shortest route for you. You want a bit more control over rotational direction, so I commented out the `transition:transform 1s ease;` in your CSS because we'll control this manually.

**JAVASCRIPT**

I borrowed [this JQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191130/2608515) and modified it so we can feed it a starting angle, and ending angle and it'll animate `#graph1` for us. (Read the link to change duration, easing, and to use the `complete` callback)

```
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, start, duration, easing, complete) {
  var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
  var step = args.step;
  return this.each(function(i, e) {
    args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
    args.step = function(now) {
      $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
    };

    $({deg: start}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
  });
};
```

I also modified your JQuery so it won't rotate counter-clockwise: when `currentRotationDegrees` is greater than `degreesToZero`, it'll subtract 360, and then use this new value as the starting position for `animateRotate().

```
if(currentRotationDegrees > degreesToZero){
    currentRotationDegrees -= 360;
}

$('#graph1').animateRotate(degreesToZero, currentRotationDegrees);
```

Here it is in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4nad31t/1/