# Please explain the meaning of $({deg: 0}) in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain to me what's the meaning of `$({deg: 0})` in [CSS rotation cross browser with jquery.animate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191058/css-rotation-cross-browser-with-jquery-animate)?

e.g.

```
$({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function(now) {
        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
        $elem.css({
            transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
    }
});
```

I'd much appreciate if you could show me the relevant jQuery official documentation about it.

Comment: i don't really understand downvote here, seems legitimate question, imho

Comment: I am surprised this has not been asked before (that I have seen on SO), but it is a little obscure. Good question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It creates a *disconnected* pseudo jQuery object with the property `deg` set to `0`.

You might have seen this before:

```
var newDiv = $('<div>', {class: "hello"});
```

Which creates a *specific* element type and sets initial properties on it. It is the same thing without the specified element type.

**Note:** this type of object is not valid for insertion into the DOM, but you can apply many useful jQuery methods to it.

So you can use information from that object to do cool things like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cfmzau1w/

```
// Create a pseudo jQuery object (not connected to a DOM element)
var po = $({
    deg: 0
});

// This is just the target object we want to change
$elem = $('#result');

// Use animate on the object, to make use of the step callback
po.animate({
    deg: 360
}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function (now) {
        // Take the computed value and use it on a real element!
        $elem.css({
            transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
    }
});
```

The reference is not obvious, but on this page http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-object it has a `jQuery(object)` method that says:

> jQuery( object )
>   object Type: PlainObject
>   A plain object to wrap in a jQuery object.

In your example the `object` is your anonymous object so the *long-hand* pseudo-code of the example is something like:

```
var anonymousObj = {
     deg: 0
};
var wrappedInAjQueryObject = jQuery(anonymousObj);
wrappedInAjQueryObject.animate(targetPropertiesAndValues, someSettingsAndCallbacksInAnObject);
```