# Rotate an object by x degree, not to x degree

Tags: jquery, html, css, gsap

How can I rotate an object by x degree and not to x degree. 
I know `transform/-webkit-transform` rotate an object by x degree, but I want something that will rotate my object from whichever angle it is in by x degree.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand you well, what you want to achieve is to have a function that rotates an element on x axis by any desired degree.

```
function AnimateRotate(d,elem){

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(now){
            elem.css({
                transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Original source by [yckart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191130/717937)