# Shiny Knob Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im working on one project and I need knobe elements (I know there is library that everyone share , but its not possible to customise it , and I need something I can put image like knobe element )

I found this library , http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/pretty-switches-css3-jquery/

And when I look at the code I dont see where Im getting input value returned ?

Has anyone use it before ? Or if you have something similar to recommend ?

Here is the code when library is called

```
$('#control').knobKnob({
        snap : 10,
        value: 154, /// How much I understand this is default value setting 
        turn : function(ratio){
            numBars = Math.round(colorBars.length*ratio);

            // Update the dom only when the number of active bars
            // changes, instead of on every move

            if(numBars == lastNum){
                return false;
            }
            lastNum = numBars;

            colorBars.removeClass('active').slice(0, numBars).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing included in the plugin that will help you retrieve the value of the knob. This means you'll have to extend it to support this feature yourself.

One way to do this is to get the value of the rotated degree of the knob.

I found a method to get this exact value [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840120/2424649).

When using that method you could retrieve the knob-value by doing:

```
getRotationDegrees($('#control .knob .top'));
```

Comment: [Here's an article that explains this technique](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

You will get the value in knobknob.js file which is in knobknob folder.

```
doc.on('mouseup.rem  touchend.rem',function(){

                knob.off('.rem');
                doc.off('.rem');

                // Saving the current rotation
                rotation = currentDeg;                  
                alert(rotation);                    
                // Marking the starting degree as invalid
                startDeg = -1;
            });.
```

alert the rotation...you will get the knob value