# Change CSS rotation value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

I have this element in my code:

```
<img id="pswheel" src="images/wheel.png" style="transform: rotate(315deg); transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;">
```

Now I want to change the rotation value from 315 to 0 on a click event. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('elementtoclick').click(function(){
   $('img').css('transform','rotate(0deg)');
})
```

Comment: You are a star...Thanks a lott..Worked

Comment: One last question..How can I get the current rotation value in a variable for example I want to do this var val = 315;

Comment: For your question check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery

Comment: I tried with the solution posted there but didn't work for me.