# Get CSS transform property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `-webkit-transform: translateY('')` property in a variable.

HTML

```
<form class="form-con" style="-webkit-transform: translateY(-802px);"></form>
```

JS

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    var current_pull = parseInt($('.form-con').css('transform').split(',')[4]);
});
```

This is returning '0', instead of the correct value.

Comment: What browser are you using?  In Chrome you have to get the value with `.css('-webkit-transform')` - your code returns undefined for that function so the split fails.  Be wary of cross-browser issues with this

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Though Jack's answer did the trick.

Comment: You'd have better to retrieve setted value from: `$('.form-con')[0].style['webkitTransform']`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    var current_pull = parseInt($('.form-con').css('transform').split(',')[5]);
});
```

Comment: Gives me always 0 back

Answer (score 41):

You can use:

```
 var obj = $('.form-con');
 var transformMatrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
   obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
   obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
   obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
   obj.css("transform");
 var matrix = transformMatrix.replace(/[^0-9\-.,]/g, '').split(',');
 var x = matrix[12] || matrix[4];//translate x
 var y = matrix[13] || matrix[5];//translate y
```

Comment: In what case would `matrix[12]` and `matrix[13]` relevant?

Comment: @StevenPalinkas: that is in case of 3d transformation where matrix of 4*4 size is defined. Check third property in doc here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Does it make sense still to differ between '-moz-transform', '-ms-transform', etc. since all browsers are compatible to 'rotate (nnn deg)' ?

Comment: Even though I prefer the regex here over the more usual approach I came across to get the values, I did notice that with a particularly small number it strips the e notation from the value - making it become `NaN`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840120/2414449):

```
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
    obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
    obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    //return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
    return angle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of properties is indeterminate.

```
var matrix = $obj.css('transform');
var translate = {};

// translateX 
var matchX = matrix.match(/translateX\((-?\d+\.?\d*px)\)/);
if(matchX) {
  translate.x = matchX[1];
}

// translateY
var matchY = matrix.match(/translateY\((-?\d+\.?\d*px)\)/);
if(matchY) {
  translate.y = matchY[1];
}

console.log(translate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transform string using outerHTML rather than matrix3d because it doesn't recalculate vw when resizing:

```
let imgEl = $('img');
let defaultMatrix = imgEl.prop('outerHTML');
defaultMatrix = getStringProp(defaultMatrix, 'style="', '"');
console.log(defaultMatrix);
let trZ = getStringProp(defaultMatrix, 'translate3d(', ')');
trZ = trZ.split(', ')[2];
console.log(trZ);

function getStringProp(str, first, last) {
  str = str.substring(str.indexOf(first) + first.length, str.length);
  return str.substring(str.indexOf(last) + last.length - 1, 0);
}
```

Here is the [example](https://codepen.io/pavelkhabusov/pen/GRXYQpG)