# JQuery-UI Draggable drag at mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <style>
        #draggable {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .container {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            transform: scale(1.6);
            position: relative;
            left: 300px;
            top: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

It works perfect without `transform: scale(1.6);`. However, the `#draggable` moves faster than the mouse with the transform property. How can I make it draggable and scale the container to a value like 1.65? Is there any draggable option I'm supposed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by adjusting for the `transform: scale(1.6)`. When the item is dragged, it uses it's `position` to adjust the `top` and `left` of the dragged item. With the `scale()`, these values are off and you will see the items movement move that same factor faster then the mouse.

`x1 = x * 1.6;
y1 = y * 1.6;`

To move with the mouse, we need to adjust this back to the same 1:1 (instead of 1:1.6) ratio. This can be done like so:

**jQuery > Draggable > Drag Option**

```
drag: function(e, ui) {
  // Adjust for Scale
  var myScale = parseFloat($('.container').css('transform').split(',')[3]);
  var myTop = Math.round(ui.position.top / myScale);
  var myLeft = Math.round(ui.position.left / myScale);
  ui.position = {
    top: myTop,
    left: myLeft
  };
}
```

FYI, `$('.container').css('transform')` will return: `matrix(1.6, 0, 0, 1.6, 0, 0)`. See more: [Get CSS transform property with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987596/get-css-transform-property-with-jquery)

You could hard code `1.6` into your script, but I like to keep things portable. So if you change the CSS, you don't have to change this script. See more about setting position: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1gnehyum/