# Jquery rotate not working for multiple instances of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which works fine when only one instance of the image being rotated:

```
// Next Angle Variable
nextAngle = 0;

$( ".portfolioDropLink" ).click(function() {

    // Icon Variable
    var currentIcon = $(this).find(".fa-angle-down");

    // Rotate Icon
    currentIcon.rotate(getNextAngle());

    function getNextAngle() {
        nextAngle += 180;
        if(nextAngle >= 360) {
            nextAngle = 0;
        }
        return nextAngle;
    }

});
```

When two instances of the `.portfolioDropLink` class are present the `nextAngle` variable clashes, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Does the plugin you're using allow you to get the angle from the icon itself? If so you would not need to store a `nextAngle` variable anymore, you would just get the rotation and use that.

Comment: you can start by providing more info. As in Jquery version and some of the structure of your page, jsfiddle is also a acceptable first step. The more info you give, the faster your question will be answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to [retrieve the angle by getting its CSS value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery)

Another solution could be to store the angle with the elements' data:

```
$( ".portfolioDropLink" ).click(function() {

    // Icon Variable
    var currentIcon = $(this).find(".fa-angle-down");

    // Rotate Icon
    currentIcon.rotate(getNextAngle(this));

    function getNextAngle(el) {
        //Get Value and Parse
        var currentAngle = el.getAttribute('data-angle');
        if (parseInt(currentAngle) == NaN) currentAngle = 0;

        //Get Next Value
        nextAngle =  parseInt(currentAngle) + 180;
        if(nextAngle >= 360) {
            nextAngle = 0;
        }

        //Set Value and Return
        el.setAttribute('data-angle', nextAngle)
        return nextAngle;
    }

});
```