# Return CSS animation starting position

Tags: css, css-animations

I wanted to finish the animation and smoothly return to its original state, but there is a jump.

Required condition, duration of the animation can be anything.

I tried to do this using CSS features.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').addClass('stop');
}, 2500);
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px 150px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
            animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
}
.stop {
    -webkit-animation: none;
            animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes wiggle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @misterManSam I added a new class, and tell him, hey, I don't need infinity, repeat once and finish, but it does not work.

Comment: I have created an almost simple animation that can stop and rotate back to the beginning. Please check my updated answer :)

Comment: @misterManSam Thank you! Your solution works, but I think there is a simple solution, using the capabilities of the CSS.
At the moment it is the simplest [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/0hmk5syj/)
Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: It's a tricky one. With CSS animation it needs to have the current angle of the div in order to animate to 0.  Can't get the current rotation angle without javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a stop and start animation that rotates back to the beginning. It starts and stops with buttons and could easily start on load. There is a complete demo at the bottom of this answer :)

The div looks like this:

```
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

### The infinite animation

```
.play {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
  animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
}
```

### The jQuery

1. Start the animation:

   ```
   $(".start").on("click", function() {            
     //Add infinite rotation animation classes
     $('div').addClass('play rotate');
   });
   ```
2. Stop the animation:

   Get the current rotation of the element. Adapted from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840120/2930477) by [@twist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219011/twist)

   ```
   function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
     var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
       obj.css("-moz-transform") ||
       obj.css("-ms-transform") ||
       obj.css("-o-transform") ||
       obj.css("transform");
     if (matrix !== 'none') {
       var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
       var a = values[0];
       var b = values[1];
       var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
     } else {
       var angle = 0;
     }
     return (angle < 0) ? angle += 360 : angle;
   }
   ```

   Get the current angle and then stop the current animation by removing the classes:

   ```
   $(".stop").on("click", function() {

     //Get the current rotation value
     angle1 = getRotationDegrees($('.rotate'));

     //Stop current animation
     $('div').removeClass('play rotate');
   ```
3. Create new stop animation: It looks a bit messy. Basically, it is creating a new animation with the current rotation as the starting point. The animation then takes it back to `0deg`.

   ```
   //Create stop animation and apply to new class "rotated"
     var animation = '<style type="text/css" title="stopAnimation">.rotated { -webkit-animation: stop 2s forwards; animation: stop 2s forwards; }  @-webkit-keyframes stop {  0% { transform: rotate(' + angle1 + 'deg);} 100% { transform: rotate(-0deg); } } @keyframes stop {  0% { transform: rotate(' + angle1 + 'deg);} 100% { transform: rotate(-0deg); } }</style>';          

     //Append new styles to the header
     $('head').append(animation);
   ```
4. Restart the animation:

   ```
   $(".start").on("click", function() {

     //Remove stopping animation class
     $('div').removeClass('rotated');

     //Add infinite rotation animation classes
     $('div').addClass('play rotate');
   });
   ```

The added `<style>` tag is removed after the animation is complete:

```
  //Garbage man - Remove the style tags after the animation is done
  // Important - The timeout should match the duration of the stop animation.      
  setTimeout(
  function() 
  {   
    $('style[title="stopAnimation"]').remove();    

  }, 2000);
```

### Full Example

```js
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
  var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform") ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform") ||
    obj.css("-o-transform") ||
    obj.css("transform");
  if (matrix !== 'none') {
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
  } else {
    var angle = 0;
  }
  return (angle < 0) ? angle += 360 : angle;
}


$(".stop").on("click", function() {
  
  //Get the current rotation value
  angle1 = getRotationDegrees($('.rotate'));
  
  //Stop current animation
  $('div').removeClass('play rotate');
  
  //Add class "rotated" for new animation
  $('div').addClass('rotated');


  //Create stop animation and apply to new class "rotated"
  var animation = '<style type="text/css" title="stopAnimation">.rotated { -webkit-animation: stop 2s linear forwards; animation: stop 2s linear forwards; }  @-webkit-keyframes stop {  0% { transform: rotate(' + angle1 + 'deg);} 100% { transform: rotate(-0deg); } } @keyframes stop {  0% { transform: rotate(' + angle1 + 'deg);} 100% { transform: rotate(-0deg); } }</style>';
  
  
  //Append new styles to the header
  $('head').append(animation);
  
  //Garbage man - Remove the style tags after the animation is done
  // Important - The timeout should match the duration of the stop animation.  
  setTimeout(
  function() 
  {   
    $('style[title="stopAnimation"]').remove();    

  }, 2000);
  
  


});

$(".start").on("click", function() {
  
  //Remove stopping animation class
  $('div').removeClass('rotated');
  
  //Add infinite rotation animation classes
  $('div').addClass('play rotate');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
.play {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
  animation: wiggle 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="stop">Stop!</button>
<button class="start">Start!</button>

<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution using JavaScript, for example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hmk5syj/). But I think that there is a solution to the CSS.