# How to get a css value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

So from the research I have done you just use .css(property) you want to get the value of but it does not work for me.

I have my html circle like this:

```
<div class="wheel-circle circle-1"><a class="user mc"></a></div>
```

Circle 1 will have this css(because its positioned around an element- wheel spinner)

```
 -webkit-transform: rotate(51.429deg) translate(600px) rotate(-51.429deg);
      transform: rotate(51.429deg) translate(600px) rotate(-51.429deg);
```

I want to be able to use css('transform') to get the value of the rotation on its own. Im not sure if this is possible because the transform has multiple transformations.

Has anyone any idea of an alternative method?

Comment: You can refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11840120/1719752 and https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/