# Consecutive rotations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that I apply on click:

```
$("#search").click(function()
{
  if (searchForth)
  {
    animateRotate(45,"#search");
    searchForth = false;
  }
  else
  {
    animateRotate(-45,"#search");
    searchForth = true;
  }
});
```

And the function being called:

```
function animateRotate(d,element)
{
  var elem = $(element);
  $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d},{
      duration: 600,
      step: function(now)
      {
        elem.css({
            transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
        });
      }
  });
}
```

When the function gets called, the element rotates 45 degrees from the default position, which is what I want. However, when I click on the element again, the function applies a rotation of -45 degrees, but it does so from the default position of the element instead of the position the element was left in from the previous rotation. Why is that and how can I fix it so the second animation 'picks off' from the final position of the first animation?

Comment: `$({deg: 0})` so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should save rotation angle
2. You shouldn't find elem by deg

```js
var searchForth = false;
var angle=0;
$("#search").click(function()
{
  if (searchForth)
  {
    angle += 45;
    animateRotate(angle,"#search");
    searchForth = false;
  }
  else
  {
    angle -= 45;
    animateRotate(angle,"#search");
    searchForth = true;
  }
});

function animateRotate(d,element)
{
  var elem = $(element);
  $(elem).animate({deg: d},{
      duration: 600,
      step: function(now)
      {
        elem.css({
            transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
        });
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current rotated position first and than add/remove 45 degrees from it, according to the value of `searchForth`.

Look at this for more info: [Get element -moz-transform:rotate value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270612/get-element-moz-transformrotate-value-in-jquery)

```js
var searchForth=false;
$("#rotate").click(function()
{
  if (searchForth)
  {
    animateRotate(45,this);
    searchForth = false;
  }
  else
  {
    animateRotate(-45,this);
    searchForth = true;
  }
});
function animateRotate(d,element)
{
var startDeg = getRotationDegrees($(element));
  var elem = $(element);
  $(elem).animate({deg: (startDeg + d)},{
      duration: 600,
      step: function(now)
      {
        elem.css({
            transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
        });
      }
  });
}

function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
    obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
    obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotate">Rotate me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using CSS3 transition and transform?

```js
$(function() {
  var deg = 45;
  var srh = $('#search').on('click', function(e) {
    srh.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (deg) + 'deg)');
    deg = -(deg);
  });
});
```

```css
#search {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search">Search</button>
```